# The 20-GB Storage with music, does it have to be used for music?

Tags: ubuntu-one, music

The 20-GB Storage with music, does it have to be used for music? Or can I use it for documents / whatever I want

Title prtty much says it all, just a question befor i decided if i wana take up on the offer :P

Comment: Judging from the page on the official Ubuntu about the Ubuntu One, I think its streaming music from the cloud + 20GB storage space, rather than just 20GB storage space (the offer to the right) on that page.

Answer (score 2):

You may use that storage for anything you want to; it is not limited to just music. You can store purchased music from the Ubuntu One music store, your own music, photos, documents, whatever you want. :)